# Prolog List Manipulation Assistance

Tags: list, prolog

I have a prolog homework problem that I've been working on that I'm rather stuck on. The basic problem is that I have three lists, each of which has members containing a phrase and a value. I am supposed to randomly select a member of the list, print the phrase, and repeat until I've printed phrases from at least two of the lists, and the total value of the phrases printed is at least 9.

What I've done so far: I've gone through several dozen iterations of the program, and searched the SWI documentation as well as Lean Prolog Now and stack overflow. In the process I've learned that using assert() to add an item to a list will cause corruption on a subsequent run, all variables are local, that appending a single item to an empty list does not result in a list but does result in fun error messages the next recursion, and that you can't vary a variable's value. 
My program successfully does the following: randomly chooses one of 3 lists. Randomly grabs an item from that list. Places the phrase and value from the selected item into different variables, and prints them.

Its main issue is that my list manipulation does not appear to be working. The line "append(Usedlist, Z, Usedlist3)," always fails in the second iteration of the code without throwing an error. Additionally, I believe that the member(Z, Usedlist) is not working as the rare occasions where I randomly get a repeat in the second iteration it does not function properly. However, I suspect that the fault is in the append not adding to the list properly.

Relevant code (condensed to 1 list for sanity reasons)

```
main :-
      A is 0,
      B is 0,
      C is 0,
      Num is 0,
      Usedlist = ["Garbage data1", "More garbage data"],
      prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist).

    prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist) :- Num < 9 ,
    F = [["time of day", 1], ["Season", 5], ["Yesterdays weather", 2], ["Month of last big storm", 2], ["Randomly generated riddle", 9], ["A captcha", 1], ['Current day', 6], ["Tomorrows date", 5]],

    random_member(Rand, F),
    nth0(1, Rand, Add),
    writeln(Rand),  
    nth0(0, Rand, Z),
    writeln(Usedlist),
    (   member(Z, Usedlist) ->
        writeln("Test5"),
        prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist)
    ;   writeln(Rand),
        writeln(Add),
        writeln("Test6"),
        append(Usedlist, Z, Usedlist3),
        writeln(Z),
        C3 is 1,
        Num3 is Num + Add,
        writeln(Num3),
        prologwhile(Num3, A, B, C3, Usedlist3)
    )
```

Sample output

```
[Tomorrows date,5]
[Garbage data1,More garbage data]
[Tomorrows date,5]
5
Test6
Tomorrows date
5
[time of day,1]
[Garbage data1,More garbage data|Tomorrows date]
[time of day,1]
1
Test6
false.
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us tackle it in **stages**:

## 1. Eliminate side-effects and simplify the program

I start with the following straight-forward changes of your program:

1. I **eliminate** all goals that perform I/O, since these only get in the way of the reasoning we would like to perform about the program.
2. Instead of `X is C` where `C` is a *constant*, and the variable is only used *once* in the remainder of the code, I simply use the constant `C` *directly*.

Thus, we obtain:

```
main :-
      prologwhile(0, 0, 0, 0, ["Garbage data1", "More garbage data"]).

prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist) :-
        Num < 9 ,
        F = [["time of day", 1], ["Season", 5], ["Yesterdays weather", 2], ["Month of last big storm", 2], ["Randomly generated riddle", 9], ["A captcha", 1], ['Current day', 6], ["Tomorrows date", 5]],
        random_member(Rand, F),
        nth0(1, Rand, Add),
        nth0(0, Rand, Z),
        (   member(Z, Usedlist) ->
            prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist)
        ;   append(Usedlist, Z, Usedlist3),
            Num3 is Num + Add,
            prologwhile(Num3, A, B, 1, Usedlist3)
        ).
```

Now, for readability, I make the following *additional* changes:

- I factor out the *phrases* into their own predicate
- I use **pairs** instead of lists to represent `Phrase-Value` pairs
- I use **pattern** matching and a bit more telling variable names.

In total, we now have:

```
main :-
      prologwhile(0, 0, 0, 0, ["Garbage data1", "More garbage data"]).

prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist) :-
        Num < 9 ,
        phrases(Ps),
        random_member(Phrase-Value, Ps),
        (   member(Phrase, Usedlist) ->
            prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist)
        ;   append(Usedlist, Phrase, Usedlist3),
            Num3 is Num + Value,
            prologwhile(Num3, A, B, 1, Usedlist3)
        ).

phrases(["time of day"-1,
         "Season"-5,
         "Yesterdays weather"-2,
         "Month of last big storm"-2,
         "Randomly generated riddle"-9,
         "A captcha"-1,
         'Current day'-6,
         "Tomorrows date"-5]).
```

Henceforth, I assume `phrases/1` as defined in the above snippet, and do not carry its definition along.

## 2. Find the cause of the failure

Now the actual **reasoning** about the program starts, because we have:

```
?- main.
false.
```

To help you find the mistake, I add the following definition to the program:

```
$(Goal) :-
        portray_clause(Goal),
        Goal.
```

We can use this predicate as follows in `prologwhile/5`:

```
prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist) :-
        Num < 9 ,
        phrases(Ps),
        random_member(Phrase-Value, Ps),
        (   member(Phrase, Usedlist) ->
            prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist)
        ;   $(append(Usedlist, Phrase, Usedlist3)),
            Num3 is Num + Value,
            prologwhile(Num3, A, B, 1, Usedlist3)
        ).
```

We now get:

```
?- main.
append(["Garbage data1", "More garbage data"], "A captcha", _).
append(["Garbage data1", "More garbage data"|"A captcha"], 'Current day', _).
false.
```

So here's the problem:

```
?- append(["Garbage data1", "More garbage data"|"A captcha"], 'Current day', _).
false
```

This goal *fails*, and *hence* the whole program fails.

You obviously *intended* the following:

```
append(Usedlist, [Phrase], Usedlist3)
```

i.e., you want to append a the contents of two *lists*, not that of a list and something *else*. Note that it is often a good idea to **prepend** elements in front of a list instead of *appending* them to obtain good performance, so we can write this as:

```
Usedlist3 = [Phrase|Usedlist]
```

So, the whole predicate becomes:

```
prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist) :-
        Num < 9 ,
        phrases(Ps),
        random_member(Phrase-Value, Ps),
        (   member(Phrase, Usedlist) ->
            prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist)
        ;   Usedlist3 = [Phrase|Usedlist],
            Num3 is Num + Value,
            prologwhile(Num3, A, B, 1, Usedlist3)
        ).
```

Or shorter:

```
prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist) :-
        Num < 9 ,
        phrases(Ps),
        random_member(Phrase-Value, Ps),
        (   member(Phrase, Usedlist) ->
            prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist)
        ;   Num3 is Num + Value,
            prologwhile(Num3, A, B, 1, [Phrase|Usedlist])
        ).
```

However, we still have:

```
?- main.
false.
```

To see why this *still* fails, think about the cases in which the predicate *ought to* hold. After a bit of reflection, the following is a case in which it *should* hold:

```
prologwhile(Num, _, _, _, [_,_|_]) :- Num >= 9.
```

Thus, we add the case to our program, obtaining:

```
prologwhile(Num, _, _, _, [_,_|_]) :- Num >= 9.
prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist) :-
        Num < 9 ,
        phrases(Ps),
        random_member(Phrase-Value, Ps),
        (   member(Phrase, Usedlist) ->
            prologwhile(Num, A, B, C, Usedlist)
        ;   Num3 is Num + Value,
            prologwhile(Num3, A, B, 1, [Phrase|Usedlist])
        ).
```

Note how I am using *pattern matching* on the accumulated list to detect the case that elements from at least 2 different pairs are used.

Now, we at last have:

```
?- main.
true .
```

That's pretty cool, but not *that* useful.

## 3. Report the actual solution on the toplevel

Now, it is time to ask a few deeper questions about the program. For example, what are all these arguments really doing here? Let us simply forget about `A`, `B` and `C`, obtaining:

```
main :-
      prologwhile(0, ["Garbage data1", "More garbage data"]).

prologwhile(Num, [_,_|_]) :- Num >= 9.
prologwhile(Num, Usedlist) :-
        Num < 9 ,
        phrases(Ps),
        random_member(Phrase-Value, Ps),
        (   member(Phrase, Usedlist) ->
            prologwhile(Num, Usedlist)
        ;   Num3 is Num + Value,
            prologwhile(Num3, [Phrase|Usedlist])
        ).
```

It works just as well:

```
?- main.
true .
```

On the other hand, an important thing seems to be missing, namely the phrases we have **actually used**! Let us get them by **introducing** an argument that represents them. In such situations, a useful naming convention is a pair `Ls0` and `Ls`, with `Ls0` denoting the *initial* list, and `Ls` the final one that we want the **toplevel** to report.

We can also simply forget about the "garbage" elements.

Thus the whole program becomes:

```
solution(List) :-
      prologwhile(0, [], List).

prologwhile(Num, Ls, Ls) :- Num >= 9, Ls = [_,_|_].
prologwhile(Num, Ls0, Ls) :-
        Num < 9 ,
        phrases(Ps),
        random_member(Phrase-Value, Ps),
        (   member(Phrase, Ls0) ->
            prologwhile(Num, Ls0, Ls)
        ;   Num3 is Num + Value,
            prologwhile(Num3, [Phrase|Ls0], Ls)
        ).

phrases(["time of day"-1,
         "Season"-5,
         "Yesterdays weather"-2,
         "Month of last big storm"-2,
         "Randomly generated riddle"-9,
         "A captcha"-1,
         'Current day'-6,
         "Tomorrows date"-5]).
```

Sample query:

```
?- solution(Ls).
Ls = ["Randomly generated riddle", "Season"] ;
false.
```

You can also easily *extend* this to report the **total value**, either while building the list or in a simple additional step. I leave this as an exercise. Note also that `prologwhileisnotaseasytoread` as for example `using_underscores_would_be`.

Comment: @mat: Very nice instructive answer, +s(0)!

Comment: As I've been working on this more, could you explain to me how those last two steps work again? I need to add A, B, and C back in, but I can't without the whole thing failing.